# ERROR: Query failed: Timeout in automation studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

I am running the query many times and keep receiving Time out error.

Please help me to solve the issue. Below is my sql query.

```
SELECT
    Opp.Id AS OpportunityId,
    payer.id as contactid,
    Payer.MDS_Preferred_House_Name__c AS [PAYER_PREFERRED_HOUSE_NAME],
    Payer.Mailingcity  AS [PAYER_CITY],
    Payer.MailingCountry AS [PAYER_COUNTRY],
    Payer.Mailingpostalcode AS [PAYER_POSTCODE],
    Payer.Salutation AS [PAYER_TITLE],
    Payer.FirstName AS [PAYER_FIRST_NAME],
    Payer.LastName AS [PAYER_LAST_NAME],
    CONCAT(Payer.Salutation,' ',Payer.LastName) AS [PAYER_POST_NAME],
    CONCAT('Dear',' ',Payer.Salutation,' ',Payer.LastName) AS [PAYER_SALUTATION],
    Payer.MDS_Supporter_ID__c AS [PAYER_SUPPORTER_NUMBER],
    
    Opp.MDS_Joint_Postname__c AS [MEMBERSHIP_POST_NAME],
    
    Pri.MDS_Supporter_ID__c AS [PRIMARY_SUPPORTER_NUMBER],
    Pri.FirstName AS [PRIMARY_FIRST_NAME],
    concat(Pri.Salutation,' ',Pri.LastName) AS [PRIMARY_POST_NAME],
    
    Opp.MDS_Membership_Type__c AS [MEMBERSHIP_TYPE_DESCRIPTION],
    Opp.Amount AS [MEMBERSHIP_SUBSCRIPTION_RATE],
    Opp.MDS_Count_of_Cards__c AS [NUMBER_OF_CARDS],
    /*This should be transformed to be cash or DD, anything not DD should be shown as Cash.*/
    CASE WHEN Opp.npsp4hub__Payment_Method__c != 'Direct Debit' THEN 'Cash' ELSE  Opp.npsp4hub__Payment_Method__c 
        END AS [MEMBERSHIP_PAYMENT_METHOD],
    Opp.MDS_Membership_Number__c AS [MEMBERSHIP_NUMBER],
    Opp.MDS_Send_Order_to_Recipient__c AS [MEMBERSHIP_SEND_TO_RECIPIENT],
    Opp.npe01__Membership_Start_Date__c AS [MEMBERSHIP_RENEWAL_DATE],
    payer.MailingCountry, 
    Opp.npsp4hub__Payment_Method__c, 
    Ind.MDS_Do_Not_Contact__c, 
    Opp.MDS_Installment_Period__c, 
    Opp.MDS_Membership_Type__c, 
    Opp.MDS_Indicator_For_Membership_Change__c,
'No code' AS [SEGMENT_CODE]
    
FROM ENT.[Opportunity_Salesforce_1] Opp
INNER JOIN ENT.[Contact_Salesforce_3] Payer
    ON Payer.Id = Opp.MDS_Payer__c
INNER JOIN ENT.[Contact_Salesforce_3] Pri
    ON Pri.Id = Opp.npsp__Primary_Contact__c
INNER JOIN ENT.[Individual_Salesforce_1] Ind
    ON Ind.Id = Payer.IndividualId
    

WHERE
    Opp.MDS_RecordType_Name__c = 'Gift_Membership'
    AND
    Opp.StageName IN ('Pending', 'Purchased')
    AND
    Opp.MDS_Do_Not_Renew__c = 'False'
    AND
    Payer.npsp__Deceased__c = 'False'
    AND
    Payer.MailingPostalCode NOT IN ('SL6 0GA', 'SL6 0GB')
    AND
    DATEDIFF(month, GETDATE(), Opp.npe01__Membership_Start_Date__c) = 0
    AND
    Payer.MDS_Gone_Away__c = 'False'
    AND
    Opp.MDS_Renewal_Status__c = 'Stage 1'
```

Comment: I would check out the 'Timeout' section in Adam Spriggs blog article (https://sprignaturemoves.com/troubleshooting-queries-sfmc/) with a focus on breaking apart your query into parts to get around the 30 min timeout feature in query activities.

Comment: Please update your question to include the details about the target data extension's name, primary key, fields, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just split it at the join level.  First query is an overwrite on the target DE.  Second and third queries are updates.

**Query 1 - Opportunity**

```sql
select
  Opp.Id AS OpportunityId
, Opp.MDS_Joint_Postname__c AS [MEMBERSHIP_POST_NAME] 
, Opp.MDS_Membership_Type__c AS [MEMBERSHIP_TYPE_DESCRIPTION]
, Opp.Amount AS [MEMBERSHIP_SUBSCRIPTION_RATE]
, Opp.MDS_Count_of_Cards__c AS [NUMBER_OF_CARDS]
, CASE 
    WHEN Opp.npsp4hub__Payment_Method__c != 'Direct Debit' THEN 'Cash' 
    ELSE  Opp.npsp4hub__Payment_Method__c 
  END AS [MEMBERSHIP_PAYMENT_METHOD]
, Opp.MDS_Membership_Number__c AS [MEMBERSHIP_NUMBER]
, Opp.MDS_Send_Order_to_Recipient__c AS [MEMBERSHIP_SEND_TO_RECIPIENT]
, Opp.npe01__Membership_Start_Date__c AS [MEMBERSHIP_RENEWAL_DATE]
, Opp.npsp4hub__Payment_Method__c
, Opp.MDS_Installment_Period__c
, Opp.MDS_Membership_Type__c
, Opp.MDS_Indicator_For_Membership_Change__c
, 'No code' AS [SEGMENT_CODE]
, Opp.MDS_Payer__c
, Opp.npsp__Primary_Contact__c
FROM ENT.[Opportunity_Salesforce_1] Opp
WHERE
Opp.MDS_RecordType_Name__c = 'Gift_Membership'
AND Opp.StageName IN ('Pending', 'Purchased')
AND Opp.MDS_Do_Not_Renew__c = 'False'
AND DATEDIFF(month, GETDATE(), Opp.npe01__Membership_Start_Date__c) = 0
AND Opp.MDS_Renewal_Status__c = 'Stage 1'
/* action: overwrite */
```

**Query 2 - Contact**

```sql
select
  Opp.OpportunityId
, payer.id as contactid
, Payer.MDS_Preferred_House_Name__c AS [PAYER_PREFERRED_HOUSE_NAME]
, Payer.Mailingcity  AS [PAYER_CITY]
, Payer.MailingCountry AS [PAYER_COUNTRY]
, Payer.Mailingpostalcode AS [PAYER_POSTCODE]
, Payer.Salutation AS [PAYER_TITLE]
, Payer.FirstName AS [PAYER_FIRST_NAME]
, Payer.LastName AS [PAYER_LAST_NAME]
, CONCAT(Payer.Salutation,' ',Payer.LastName) AS [PAYER_POST_NAME]
, CONCAT('Dear',' ',Payer.Salutation,' ',Payer.LastName) AS [PAYER_SALUTATION]
, Payer.MDS_Supporter_ID__c AS [PAYER_SUPPORTER_NUMBER]
, Payer.MailingCountry
, Payer.IndividualId
FROM TARGETDENAME Opp
INNER JOIN ENT.[Contact_Salesforce_3] Payer ON Payer.Id = Opp.MDS_Payer__c
where 
Payer.npsp__Deceased__c = 'False'
AND Payer.MailingPostalCode NOT IN ('SL6 0GA', 'SL6 0GB')
AND Payer.MDS_Gone_Away__c = 'False'
/* action: update -- assuming the target DE's primary key is only OpportunityId */
```

**Query 3 - Individual**

```sql
select
  Opp.OpportunityId
, Ind.MDS_Do_Not_Contact__c
FROM TARGETDENAME Opp
INNER JOIN ENT.[Individual_Salesforce_1] Ind ON Ind.Id = Payer.IndividualId
/* action: update -- assuming the target DE's primary key is only OpportunityId */
```